# Determining the power set of certain sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

1. **Question:** Let $A = \{ x,\{ x \} \}$. List all elements in $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

   **Solution:** $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ \emptyset, \{x, \{ x \} \} \}$.
2. **Question:** Let $A = \{ 1,2 \}$ and $B = \{2,3\}$. List all elements in:

   - $\mathcal{P} (A\cap B)$.

     **Solution:**  $\{ \emptyset,  \{2\} \}$.
   - $\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$.

     **Solution:** $\{ \emptyset, \{ 1,2\}, \{2,3\}\}$.

Are the solutions correct?

Comment: For future problems consider $|\mathcal{P}(A)|= 2^N$ when $|A| = N$. With this in mind you could've noticed yourself your answers (1) and (3) can't be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one should be:
$$
\{~~~\emptyset,~~\{x\},~~\{\{x\}\},~~\{x,\{x\}\} ~~~\}
$$

The second one is correct.

The third one should be:

$$
\{~~~\emptyset,~~\{1\},~~\{2\},~~\{3\},~~\{1,2\},~~\{2,3\} ~~~\}
$$